# application not listed in notification access Setting (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

my app is not listed in notification access setting screen...

i added this permission **BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE** in **manifest.xml**

opening notification access setting screen by calling this intent **startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));**

anyone implemented thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well and I made the mistake of putting the service tag outside the application tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<service android:name=".TELNotificationListening"
    android:label="@string/service_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I fixed this problem by putting the service tag inside the application tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".TELNotificationListening"
        android:label="@string/service_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

You need to create a class that extends NotificationListenerService in my case I named it TELNotificationListening. You put the name of your class in android:name="" in the service tag.

In order to extend NotificationListenerService your minimum SDK has to be set to 21.

Once you extend NotificationListenerService you can then override it's method!